# CSV to JSON conversion combining sets belong to same key

Tags: python, json

I am trying to generate a json request form from csv file. This request form is required by the REST webservice.

Sample Input File :

```
Id,LineNo,Amt,ReceivedDt,FromDt,ToDate
123545,1,1000.00,2019-02-01T00:00:00,2019-02-01T00:00:00,2019-02-01T00:00:00
123545,2,200.00,2019-02-01T00:00:00,2019-02-01T00:00:00,2019-02-01T00:00:00
123546,1,200.00,2019-02-01T00:00:00,2019-02-01T00:00:00,2019-02-01T00:00:00
```

There are more records in the file following above structure. One Id can have multiples Line No and all those records should be in single set.

Desired Format :

```
{
    "consumerData": {
        "clientCode": "CLINIC", 
        "instance": "P", 
        "userId": ""
    }, 
    "gfsauthdata": [
        {
            "ToDate": "2019-02-01T00:00:00", 
            "ReceivedDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00", 
            "Id": "123545", 
            "LineNo": "1", 
            "Amt": "1000.00", 
            "FromDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00"
        }, 
        {
            "ToDate": "2019-02-01T00:00:00", 
            "ReceivedDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00", 
            "Id": "123545", 
            "LineNo": "2", 
            "Amt": "200.00", 
            "FromDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "consumerData": {
        "clientCode": "CLINIC", 
        "instance": "P", 
        "userId": ""
    }, 
    "gfsauthdata": 
        {
            "ToDate": "2019-02-01T00:00:00", 
            "ReceivedDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00", 
            "Id": "123546", 
            "LineNo": "1", 
            "Amt": "200.00", 
            "FromDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00"
        }
}
```

I am not able to separate records different sets. Please suggest some way to separate it out. I am using below code which is transferring csv to json but all records are coming in single set.

***Code :***

```
import json,csv

with open('Test.csv') as f:
    inputfile = csv.DictReader(f)
    output = []
    for row in inputfile :
        #j = json.dumps(row, indent=4)
        output.append(row)

        data = {
            'consumerData': {
                        'clientCode': 'CLINIC',
                        'instance': 'P',
                        'userId': ''
                    },
            'gfsauthdata': output
           }

print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking about your data structure wrong.  You should use the dict like this:

```
data[userid] = { 
        "type": "CLINIC", 
        "instance": "P",
        "gfsauthdata": [
        {
            "ToDate": "2019-02-01T00:00:00", 
            "ReceivedDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00", 
            "Id": "123545", 
            "LineNo": "1", 
            "Amt": "1000.00", 
            "FromDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00"
        }, 
        {
            "ToDate": "2019-02-01T00:00:00", 
            "ReceivedDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00", 
            "Id": "123545", 
            "LineNo": "2", 
            "Amt": "200.00", 
            "FromDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00"
        }
    ]}
}
```